# set path for RUNNING_PID in play server application - Windows system

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

Is there a way to configure the RUNNING_PID file path in play server to the home directory of the user on Windows system.
I know one way is to configure path in application.conf, but that path may not exist on user system at all and it would be a static path.
Can the path be set programatically to user home directory when server starts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Play documentation, you can specify the pidfile path at start with the option:

```
$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/play.pid
```

This will work also on Windows

[Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Changing-the-path-of-RUNNING_PID)